# Using Unicode Greek symbols for variables in python 3

Tags: python, unicode

I can use Unicode symbols inside Python. As a researcher this excites me because it could make my equations more readable.

1. Will there be problems writing complicated equations involving several such variables?
2. Will the performance of the code be affected?

For an example, this is a piece from my re-written code with Unicode characters:

```
# Use iterative solver to find the solution
φ_equi = math_op.itr_sol_search(still, 0, φ_max)

# Evaluate the slop of the GZ Curve at the new equilibrium angle
GZ_slope = math_op.cspline_deriv(φ_equi, φ_pts, GZ_pts) * 180/π

N_Roll_MI = (m * g * GM_T * Tφ**2)/(4 * π**2)
Om_R = sqrt( (m * g * GZ_slope) / N_Roll_MI )
```

Comment: I think you should stick to PEP8 [variable naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Check this on usage and restrictions of [Unicode variable names in Python 3](https://python-3-for-scientists.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python3_features.html).  Says: "Unlike Julia or Swift, which allow any unicode symbol to represent a variable (including emoji) Python 3 restricts variable names to unicode characters that represent characters in written languages. In contrast, Python 2 could only use the basic ASCII character set for variable names."

Comment: 1) How to you type a `φ` on your keyboard?

Comment: Typing φ on keyboard is difficult, I use excel symbols. Any problems regarding performance or long equations ?

Comment: So, if typing one character is difficult already, I guess you have answered the question yourself.

Comment: I am sorry when I mentioned problems, I meant problems related to the interpreter due to use of many encoded characters, whether it will slow down the code or cause some errors. @KlausD.

Comment: Related post on coding [mathematical formulas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/is-it-bad-to-use-unicode-characters-in-variable-names)

Comment: If your using python in Jupyter notebooks you can just type the name of the letter after a backslash and then complete it by typing tab and the character is auto-magically inserted! i.e. "\alpha[tab]" gets you α and if your transcribing something written in mathese it really helps.

Comment: @KlausD. To enter "φ" or any other Greek letter, one option is to add Greek as a keyboard input language. Then you simply switch languages by hitting alt+shift (windows) or super+space (ubuntu default, if I remember well)

Comment: @KlausD. Now normally your keybaord will not "physically" show which english letter you have to hit so that the corresponding greek letter is typed in, unless you are a greek speaker and you own a greek keyboard like me :) Luckily, most keys are where you "would expect them to be", e.g. φ is under F, λ is under L, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't, you actually decrease readability. The give-away is that you need to comment the variables what they do. Instead of writing `φ_pts` and a comment, you could name it `equilibrium_angle` directly. Now almost everyone can understand it, not only a researcher that is familiar with the subject matter.

Maths with one letter Greek variable names stems from a long ago time and is optimised for writing with chalk on shale or a blackboard. Computer programming is not the same, so do not blindly apply tools and traditions from other subjects.

The problems are not in the area you are asking about, there are no foreseeable technical or performance problem. It's the human factor you need to worry about.

Comment: *"...is optimised for writing with chalk on shale or a blackboard"* -- in some areas of mathematics, single letter variable names expose structure or relationships between abstract variables, which are at least as important as whatever the variables themselves might represent. I think it would lead to less readable mathematics if everyone suddenly started following the conventional programming conventions of descriptive variable names. But mathematics has the advantage that symbol usage is either defined in text or consistent within a given subject/textbook/...

Answer (score 0):

> As a researcher

If you implement an algorithm described by a paper, the script will be easier to read if it uses the exact same notation as in the paper.

If the paper uses Greek letters, it should be okay to use Greek letters as variables. Once the script is tested and validated, it probably will not be modified much, so it's not a problem to have to copy-paste `φ, δ, ε, α`.

In the general case, it's probably better to stick to descriptive ascii variable names.